# Going back to a running instalation process after being disconnected

Tags: linux, ssh, process

I was running an instillation through remote access using ssh shell.
and didn't look at the screen for a while(my bad).

when I go back to that console I find it was asking for a path like:

```
Enter custom ***** directory path [/apps/****/****/**]?
```

All I had to do is press enter and after that connection got disconnected.

Is there a way to go back to that screen.?

---

I can find the process through ps -ef

```
user   9003  8751  0 14:42 pts/2    00:00:00 /bin/sh ./input Enter custom **** directory path .* Must enter a valid pathname /apps/****/****/**
```

Comment: not a solution to your current problem, but to avoid it the next time: always use "screen" or "tmux" when running something remote.

Answer (score 0):

I found another thread at U&L:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/31824/how-to-attach-terminal-to-detached-process

perhaps the answer does work for your problem.